# password and username validation in PHP

Tags: php, passwords

i have this information on my database...

Username  -  kam, mav, shin

Password - kam, mav, shin

this is my code...

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);
$tbl2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE `username` =   
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' and `password` =   
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl2))

    if (($row['username']==$_POST['username'])&&($row['password']==$_POST['password']))
        {   
            echo " ";
    }

    if (($row['username']!=$_POST['username'])&&($row['password']!=$_POST['password']))
        {
            header("location: /login.php?codeError=1");
            die;
        }
?>
```

the problem is, if i enter the username "mav" and the password is "kam", it still go through the next page. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You should just check if the query returns any rows with `mysql_num_rows()`:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

$tbl2 = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `password`  FROM `tablename` WHERE 
                    `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND 
                    `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'
                   ");

$rows = mysql_num_rows($tbl2);

if($rows){
    // user and password exists in db
} else {
    // does not exist
    header("location: /login.php?codeError=1");
    die;
}
```

Like I told you in previous question, try to move from `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: OP's while statement with mysql_fetch_array should be doing the job(check if there is a record with given username and password) already without a row count I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but why not try it this way:

```
if (($row['username']==$_POST['username'])&&($row['password']==$_POST['password']))
    {   
        echo " ";
    }else{
      header("location: /login.php?codeError=1");
      die;
    }
```

I don't understand why you need two if statements here, it's only boolean and the result will either be true or false.

Hope this helps :)!

Comment: i tried it, but it only do the same thing. But the thing is, my database has 3 rows which consist of username and password. The username mav has a password mav. The username kam has a password kam. The username shin has a password shin. The problem is, if i enter the username "mav" and the password is "kam", instead of printing the error message, it still go through the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for validation already in your query. If the user entered username and password correctly and only then, the query returns a row, containing that data.

So you only have to count the rows returned bye your Query. If it is below 1, then the user is not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if (($row['username']==$_POST['username'])&&($row['password']==$_POST['password']))
        {   
            echo " ";
    }

 else 
        {
            header("location: /login.php?codeError=1");
            die();
        }
```

**Anyway**, a nice way to address this kind of issues is temporary printing on screen the variables (as a debug).

```
echo $row['username']." ".$_POST['username']." ".$row['password']." ".$_POST['password']
```

see if the variables are actually there of if there are issues with your DB query or with the form that posts the data.